# How to properly set typescript in monorepo so it compiles private packages?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, nestjs, turborepo

Currently I have setup a monorepo with turborepo that has Nestjs as BE and Nextjs as FE.

I want to reuse prisma definitions so naturally I split it into its own package and implemented its own tsconfig. At the index of my database package (where the prisma is), i have this simple code:

`export * from "@prisma/client";`

Both of my Backend and Frontend now have the same dependencies:
`backend -> database` and `frontend -> database`

My FE is compiling fine and I can use the definition from my prisma, however the NestJS apps is not compiling TS in database package and it has this error, i reckon it is related to the tsconfig, it seems that NestJS (my backend) does not want to compile the private package dependencies, thus it doesn't recognise 'export'.

```
core:dev: export * from "@prisma/client";
core:dev: ^^^^^^
core:dev: 
core:dev: SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
```

can anyone please point me what is wrong with my repo?

Do i need to build the database package first before importing in nestjs app? if so, how come the client works without building it first?

this is my tsconfig for backend in `server/core/tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "extends": "tsconfig/server.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
  },
}
```

this is my tsconfig for front end (which works fine) in `apps/web/tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "extends": "tsconfig/nextjs.json",
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

and the extensions,

`tsconfig/server.json`:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig",
  "extends": "./base.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "incremental": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "strictBindCallApply": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": false
  }
}
```

`tsconfig/nextjs.json`:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig",
  "display": "Next.js",
  "extends": "./base.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "incremental": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve"
  },
  "include": ["src", "next-env.d.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

[My repo is open source here](https://github.com/Hublr-co/wealth-wallet)

Answer (score 5):

UPDATE: See my [series on Sharing TypeScript with Nx and Turborepo](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/sharing-typescript-with-nx-and-turborepo-part-1-introduction-to-monorepos-d8d54b805e46).

The problem is that TypeScript isn't being transpiled. The Next.js builder automatically transpiles dependent packages, which is why the problem does not exist for Next.js apps. All other apps will have to do the transpilation manually.

For each package required by a non-Next.js application, build the package to a package-local `dist` directory. For example:

```
// packages/mypackage/package.json
{
  "name": "@myrepo/mypackage",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "source": "src/index.ts",
  "types": "src/index.ts",
  "files": [
    "dist/**"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "clean": "rm -rf .turbo && rm -rf node_modules && rm -rf dist",
    "dev": "tsc -w",
    "lint": "TIMING=1 eslint \"src/**/*.ts*\"",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-presets/node"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint-config-custom": "*",
    "jest-presets": "*",
    "tsconfig": "*"
  }
}
```

```
// packages/mypackage/tsconfig.json
{
  "extends": "tsconfig/base.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["ES2019"],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "rootDir": "./src"
  },
  "include": ["*.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"],
  "exclude": ["dist", "build", "node_modules"]
}
```

Many of Vercel's example repos, such as the [kitchen sink example](https://github.com/vercel/turbo/tree/main/examples/kitchen-sink), configure `types` as follows in `package.json`:

`"types": "dist/index.d.ts"`

But this requires you to rebuild the package after each change to the package in order to have VSCode recognize the change from other packages. To have VSCode instantly type-check against a non-Next.js internal package, use this instead:

`"types": "src/index.ts"`

NOTE: It may be that you have to use the former `types` in publishable repos. I haven't tried yet.